# why they are different

Tags: go, types

In Golang spec:

```
type (
    T0 []string
    T1 []string
)
```

it says T0 and T1 are different because they are named types with distinct declarations.but there is a rule:
**Two named types are identical if their type names originate in the same TypeSpec.**
so why T0 and T1 are different?

---

EDIT:

in spec it also says:

> A type declaration binds an identifier, the type name, to a new type
>   that has the same underlying type as an existing type, and operations
>   defined for the existing type are also defined for the new type. **The
>   new type is different from the existing type.**

Comment: @JimB: "`Two slice types are identical if they have identical element types`." Not true for defined types: [Type identity](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity). `A defined type is always different from any other type.`

Comment: @shx: The current version of The Go Programming Language Specification is at https://golang.org/ref/spec. Where are you getting your quotes from?

Comment: @peterSO, yes, didn’t mean it asan answer, just trying to figure out where that quote came from in the first place and why this is a question at all.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
type (
    T0 []string
    T1 []string
)
```

> The Go Programming Language Specification
>
> Version of June 28, 2017
>
> A type definition creates a new, distinct type with the same
>   underlying type and operations as the given type, and binds an
>   identifier to it.
>
> ```
> TypeDef = identifier Type .
> ```
>
> The new type is called a defined type. It is different from any other
>   type, including the type it is created from.
>
> A defined type is always different from any other type. Otherwise, two
>   types are identical if their underlying type literals are structurally
>   equivalent; that is, they have the same literal structure and
>   corresponding components have identical types.

T0 and T1 are defined types and are, therefore, different.

---

**References:**

> [The Go Programming Language
>   Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> Version of June 28, 2017
>
> [Types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types)
>
> A type determines a set of values together with operations and methods
>   specific to those values. A type may be denoted by a type name, if it
>   has one, or specified using a type literal, which composes a type from
>   existing types.
>
> Named instances of the boolean, numeric, and string types are
>   predeclared. Other named types are introduced with type declarations.
>
> [Type declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations)
>
> A type declaration binds an identifier, the type name, to a type. Type
>   declarations come in two forms: alias declarations and type
>   definitions.
>
> ```
> TypeDecl = "type" ( TypeSpec | "(" { TypeSpec ";" } ")" ) .
> TypeSpec = AliasDecl | TypeDef .
> ```
>
> Alias declarations
>
> An alias declaration binds an identifier to the given type.
>
> ```
> AliasDecl = identifier "=" Type .
> ```
>
> Within the scope of the identifier, it serves as an alias for the
>   type.
>
> Type definitions
>
> A type definition creates a new, distinct type with the same
>   underlying type and operations as the given type, and binds an
>   identifier to it.
>
> ```
> TypeDef = identifier Type .
> ```
>
> The new type is called a defined type. It is different from any other
>   type, including the type it is created from.
>
> [Type identity](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity)
>
> Two types are either identical or different.
>
> A defined type is always different from any other type. Otherwise, two
>   types are identical if their underlying type literals are structurally
>   equivalent; that is, they have the same literal structure and
>   corresponding components have identical types.